# loading templates from various html file in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to store templates in different html files and load them.

What I am trying to achieve is, when the dropdown is changed, I need to load the particular html file. But it is not even hitting the controller of the file  i am loading. What am i doing wrong

**Index.html**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Menu.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MenuApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainMenu">
        <div ng-include src="getView()"></div>
        <select ng-model="Template" ng-change="ChangeTemplate()">
            <option value="ListItems">ListItems</option>
            <option value="BorderedItems">BorderedItems</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ListItems.html** (sample template)

```
<div ng-app="Menu">
    <div ng-controller="LoadMenu">
        <ol ng-repeat="items in MenuItems">
            <li>{{item}}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Menu.js**

```
(function () {
    angular
    .module('MenuApp', [])
    .controller('MainMenu', MainMenuControllerFunction)
    .factory('LoadMenu',['$http',LoadingMenuItemsService]);

    function MainMenuControllerFunction($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
        $scope.Text = "Hello";
        $scope.MenuItems = getMenuItems();
        function getMenuItems() {
            $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vigneshvdm/dc8632bde4e010336356/raw/4fe500385f3249b8bc717d5022c50abb0e07ba75/news").then(function (response) {
                $scope.MenuItems=response.data.array;
            });

        };
        $scope.ChangeTemplate = function () {
            var template = $templateCache.get('../Html/'+$scope.Template+'.html');
        };
        $scope.getView = function () {
            return "ListItems.html";
        };
    };

    function LoadingMenuItemsService() {
        var MenuItems;
            $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vigneshvdm/dc8632bde4e010336356/raw/4fe500385f3249b8bc717d5022c50abb0e07ba75/news").then(function (response) {
                MenuItems=response.data.array;
            });
        return MenuItems;
    };

    function ConsumeMenu() {
        //$scope.MenuItems = MenuApp.LoadMenu;
        alert("");
    };

    angular.module('Menu', ['MenuApp'])
    .controller('LoadMenu', ConsumeMenu);


})();
```

Comment: I would do `ng-include="getView();"`, and are you sure you are giving the good relative path in `getView` ?

Comment: yeah. Is it not possible to have a controller/module in the template file?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/aVSBI4RxwoR0l4opHeqL?p=preview
@PierreEmmanuelLallemant check this link. The first option is not loading the items

Answer (score 2):

Do not use functions in templates when you can avoid this.

```
<select ng-model="template">
  <option value="test.html">first</option>
  <option value="test2.html">second</option>
</select>
<div ng-include="template"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/osB9UiSzvF4IoqkizcOP?p=preview

Comment: Thank Petr. I am trying to have a controller,module in the template files as well. http://plnkr.co/edit/aVSBI4RxwoR0l4opHeqL?p=preview
check this

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use angularjs directives in this case. By using them you could store templates in different html files.

Comment: do you have any fiddle/plunkr links?